# Fastest way to check does jQuery object have any matching element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have huge tree view and one the branches is in variable called `$branch` and now I want to check does that branch contain **none** or **more than one element** with *expand* classes. In other words boolean should be returned as soon as one match is found.

Okay, I can do this with `$branch.find('.expand').length > 0`, but is there a better way that would stop on the first matching element and therefore would be faster?

I think using `first()` reduces existing set to length of one, so I would have use `find()` and then reduce?

Ps. As you noticed in the example I used `find()` because I want to go deeper than just children of the `$branch`

Comment: Will `.expand` always be a direct child of `$branch`? Or is it deeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard CSS selectors like this use the native DOM method querySelectorAll(). I.e. they run in the browser's native code and they're fast. Unless you've got reason to think that doing the above is slow, I doubt you need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to take a look at the [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method.

```
var $branchesWithExpand = $branch.has('.expand');
```

Comment: Does it check direct children or deeper like find()?

Comment: It checks all descendants, not just direct children.